# How to force Google Address Validation to return a value for county?

Tags: curl, google-api

Is there a way to force  Google Address Validation to return a value for county?

I created a file: request.json:

```
{
"address":  {<br/>
"regionCode": "US",<br/>
"addressLines": \["12600 E ARAPAHOE RD","","CENTENNIAL","CO","80112-3870","USA"\]<br/>
},<br/>
"enableUspsCass": true<br/>
}<br/>
```

Then executed:

```
curl -s -X POST -d @request.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "https://addressvalidation.googleapis.com/v1:validateAddress?key=&lt;apikey&gt;"
```

"county" does not appear in the name name/value pairs.

I also inserted:

"locality" : "CENTENNIAL",
to request.json but still the response has no value for "county".

I've validated several thousand addresses. None have county in the response.

I only get "county" when validating the GAV demo address:

"addressLines": ["1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy"],

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question with proper formatting as per [code block].

Comment: Sorry. The "code block" doesn't provide tips on writing questions which have JSON. And the tips it provides - like with formatting links - weren't helpful.  I formated the question to be easy to read? What should I improve first?

Comment: There is no JSON formatting. It's much simpler than that: just code blocks and links. Also all the HTML you inserted into your question is ignored ... unless you put it in a code block (so people could ask question about HTML). You can use the buttons at the top of the [edit] window to help you out, and the preview below that to see what it will look like.

Comment: What do you mean the HTML inserted into my question is ignored. The question rendered with the HTML. And I used the preview to see what the code looks like. I used the edit window too. Just like you recommended.